# Как убрать верхний отступ в activity?

Tags: java, android, xml

Использую прозрачный toolbar и столкнулся с такой проблемой не получаеться убрать верхнюю линию в activity.
Вот мой код:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/actionbar_opacity"
    app:theme="@style/TransparentToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Манифест:

```
<activity
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:name=".SimpleScannerActivity"/>
```

стаилс:

```
<style name="TransparentToolbar" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    </style>
```

[image: Activity]

Comment: Какую верхнюю линию, где часы и уведомления что ли? или у меня с монитором что то не так, я никаких других линий сверху не вижу :(

Comment: Да верно, именно где часы

Comment: Это Status Bar. Вот https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

Comment: Так не работает, какаято ерунда происходит с верху вниз эта белая полоса( Status Bar) переместилась

Comment: Насколько я знаю, можно включить режим витрины. Тогда Status bar будет по умолчанию скрыт. Но работает только на высоких API. То ли с Android 5+, то ли 6+.

Comment: Это к сожалению тоже не подойдет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```